How to compile multiple LaTeX articles into a single PDF journal document?
I'm struggling to compile multiple scientific articles into a single PDF, structured like a journal or book, using LaTeX.
So far, I've tried using the standalone and subfiles packages with \documentclass{article}.
I'm also working with a custom class, which could be contributing to the issue. I simplified the approach by avoiding custom classes, but I still can't get the desired result: a single PDF document that collects multiple scientific articles as distinct chapters or sections.
At the moment, I'm encountering a mix of issues: overlapping authors and affiliations, improper formatting, and a generally broken PDF.
I'm unsure of the best approach for this. Should I compile each article into its own PDF (which I can do), and then combine them later? If so, how do I manage consistent page numbering and generate a table of contents? This approach seems problematic because of those features, and I'm not sure it's the right path.
What would be the best way to structure a LaTeX project like this? Should I focus on specific packages or workflows? Any guidance or resources would be greatly appreciated.

@Fran your answer there isn't compatible with current latex, is it? I don't think combine is usable with current releases. (tell me if I'm misremembering or have it confused with something else?)

welcome! print or electronic publication? do you need hyperlinks? if you compile the documents separately, hyperlinks will break. (there are some things you can do to try to put them back, I believe, but I've never tried myself.) but for print, that's certainly the most straightforward option: just remove the page numbers from the papers and add headers and footers when the pdfs are included. it's also easy to add entries to the table of contents for each pdf. o/w, I'd use standalone as that works for me. but you've not shown any code, so can't say why it doesn't work for you.

@cfr My old answer is really about paper and journal although I mention combine as alternative (that in that time It was usable). Anyway, regardless that  the answer is outdated in that aspect, the question is not, and this seems to me a clear duplicate.

@Fran I guess we don't really know enough. i.e. the OP says the custom class was dropped to simplify, but was that just for the mwe and the custom class has to be used? or is the OP free to substitute e.g. paper or whatever. personally, I don't like solutions which require me to remove the possibility of compiling the documents standalone, but that might be just fine with the OP.

I don't know whether to answer this question or the proposed duplicate, but I would use standalone plus titling together with whichever class you prefer. You've not said what code you used or in what errors you got, so I can't know why whatever you tried failed.
Your main document then looks like this:
\documentclass[<options>]{<custom class>}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{titling}
<whatever else>
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Editor}
\date{Date}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\let\tableofcontents\relax
<etc.>
\input{<filename1>}
\input{<filename2>}
<etc.>
\end{document}

Each \input file should look like this:
\documentclass[<options>]{<some class>}
<whatever>
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}
\maketitle
<content>
\end{document}

The titling package enables you to use \title, \maketitle etc. multiple times and to customise the title format, if desired.
The standalone package, when used this way, discards everything in the \input documents' preambles. This is important. That stuff is ignored. So if you need some package for the included article to compile, you either need to include that package in the preamble of the main document or to use
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

which tells standalone to combine the preambles of all the files read. This requires an additional compilation to incorporate the results.
The advantage of this solution is that you can use whatever class(es) you please to compile both the main and individual documents and retain the ability to compile the articles standalone. If you put e.g. configuration for paper size, layout, headers, footers etc. in the preambles, you can have completely different settings for each document, while ensuring consistency for the main document.
This is not specific to journals or articles, of course. (I actually use this method for something different.) Whether the result 'looks like' a journal is entirely up to the choices set in the document's preamble.

I hadn't actually decided where to post this and accidentally submitted it. But I can delete it if appropriate.
